# Can I use Mongo DB with Windows client side applications?

Tags: windows, mongodb, client-side, database

I want to use a thin database (Not much data say 2-3 tables with 500 rows) with Windows client side application. Can I use Mongo DB for the sake.

Any experience?

Thanks

Comment: Technically yes, but I'd suggest RavenDB for .Net (http://ravendb.net/)

Comment: I use MongoDB in a windows + java environment and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks guys... But how can I install it on client machine.. Is there any waY?

Comment: The binaries are here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+Windows

Comment: have you checked the official MongoDB website yet?
http://www.mongodb.org/
they have tutorials on everything, besides you can easilly run mongoDB on a windows environment and they also explain how to easilly set it as a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use MongoDB for the sake of using it.  It is designed for storing "Big Data", but it will also work with smaller data sets.